# TypeError: _this.state.answers.push is not a function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an button that adds stuff to a few arrays. When using .push the elements add correctly (as in it looks like the for loop is used) but when I click the button a second time I get the above error. Here's some pieces of my code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      key: uuid(),
      title: "",
      author: "",
      questions: [],
      answers: []
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  //yada yada

  addQuestion = () => {
    questionNum++;
    this.setState({
      questions: this.state.questions.concat(["question", "hi"])
    });
    console.log(this.state.questions);
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      this.setState({
        answers: this.state.answers.push({
          answerChoice: "",
          key: uuid()
        })
      });
    }
    console.log(this.state.answers);
    console.log(questionNum);
    console.log(this.state.title);
    console.log(this.state.author);
  };

  render() {
    //yada yada
    <div>
      <form>
        <div className="Intro">
          Give your Quiz a title:{" "}
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.title}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            name="title"
          />
          <br />
          Who's the Author?{" "}
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.author}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            name="author"
          />
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
        <div className="questions">
          Now let's add some questions... <br />
          {this.addQuestion}
        </div>
      </form>
      <button onClick={this.addQuestion}>Add Question</button>
    </div>;
    //yada yada
  }
}
export default App;
```

However when I replace

```
this.setState({
   answers: this.state.answers.push({
     answerChoice: '',
     key: uuid()
   })
})
```

with

```
this.setState({
  answers: this.state.answers.concat({
    answerChoice: '',
    key: uuid()
  })
})
```

it seems as though my for loop doesn't work (because four of these things are not added). I am very new to React and JS so any tips would help.

Thanks!

Comment: You are calling `this.state.answers.push()` which you shouldn't do (since it mutates the state directly). This function, while adding the passed element to the array, returns the `.length`, not the new array. Which means you're setting `answers` to a number, then try to call `.push()` on it. Just use `.concat()` instead, which a) doesn't mutate the original array b) returns a new array

Comment: Oh ok, so when i use `.concat` it doesn't seem to work properly, is there a flaw in my logic? And why does the for loop there work properly when i use `.push` there instead?

Comment: Try using the prevState classback for `setState` when comparing to the current state. For example: `this.setState(prevState => ({ answers: [ ...prevState.answers, { answerChoice: '', key: uuid() } ] }));`

Comment: @dorkycam Should be `.concat([{…}])`. Concat accepts another array.

Comment: Off topic: You might find it a lot more pleasant to group your logs together as well: `console.log(this.state.answers, questionNum, this.state.title, this.state.author);`

Comment: Omg, I didn't even think of that lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `push`, as it would alter the array currently in your state.

When you update state that is derived from what is currently in your state, it's best to give `setState` a function and return the state changes from that. Otherwise there is a risk of overwriting state updates, which is what is happening in your second example.

You can instead spread the current array you have in state and add your new object to it.

```
this.setState(previousState => {
  return {
    answers: [...previousState.answers, { answerChoice: '', key: uuid() }]
  };
});
```

You can also group your state updates together and use `setState` only once if you would prefer:

```
addQuestion = () => {
  questionNum++;
  this.setState(previousState => {
    const questions = [...previousState.questions, "question", "hi"];
    const answers = [...previousState.answers];

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      answers.push({
        answerChoice: "",
        key: uuid()
      });
    }

    return { questions, answers };
  });
});
```

Comment: Not to mention it returns the new length, not the new array

Comment: Ahhhh, ok. This seemed to have fixed the issues I was having. Thanks loads!